# Is it possible to run uipath process using python

Tags: python, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I created a ui path process which login to a website and downloads the data. Now I want to automate the process and it should trigger everyday and should download the data. I tried using uipath orchestrator but I want to know where we can trigger the same uipath process using python code. **Like can we run trigger the uipath process using python script ?**. When we run the file it should start the uipath process. Please help me with an explanation for it.

I tried the process to trigger daily using orchestrator but at some point my license for machine has expired so I want to know can we trigger the same using any python script or library.

If it is possible then please share the process to do so :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423511/can-uipath-process-be-converted-into-binary-executable/62431924#62431924

Answer (score 0):

You can use UiRobot.exe and call it from pythons subprocess:

Since I no longer use UiPath (Great but expensive), I shamely copied from [here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/start-robot-process-from-python-script-add-arguments-as-parameters/528550/2):

```py
def RunningUiPathProject(arg1):
    """
    You can design this function as you please with any number of arguments going into the cmd_str variable
    """
    import subprocess
    cmd_str = "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Programs\UiPath\Studio\UiRobot.exe  execute --file 'C:\Users\%USER%\Documents\UiPath\_Nugets\YourUiPATHPROJECT.1.0.3.nupkg'  --input '{'in_InputDataFolder':ARG1} --entry 'YOURENTRYPOINT.xaml'".Replace("ARG1",arg1)
    subprocess.run(cmd_str)
```